# Bulk create or update objects in database model in Django based on excel file

Tags: python, django, pandas

So I have following excel file:

```
CustomerName    ChannelName MarketName
Cust-1          Chan-2  Market-1
Cust-1          Chan-2  Market-1
Cust-1          Chan-2  Market-1
Cust-1          Chan-3  Market-4
Cust-1          Chan-2  Market-5
Cust-2          Chan-2  Market-6
Cust-1          Chan-1  Market-7
Cust-1          Chan-2  Market-8
Cust-2          Chan-3  Market-9
Cust-3          Chan-4  Market-10
```

Which I load to dataframe using Pandas and then I iterate over rows to save every unique customer name market and channel combination I have in this file to my database.Which means that of the first 3 rows  in the example only one object should be created since they are all the same.

My customer model in Django is the following:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    """
    Stores a single customer, related to :model:`customers.Market` and :model:`customers.Channel`
    and :model:`warehouses.Warehouse`
    """
    market = models.ForeignKey(to="Market", default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Market", help_text="Market id")
    channel = models.ForeignKey(to="Channel", default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Channel", help_text="Channel id")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, default=None, verbose_name="Customer Name", help_text="Customer Name")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And this is how I am saving objects to the database pased on this dataframe:

```
def transform_df_to_clientmodel(df):
    """Save all unique customers to database"""

    df.apply(lambda row: bulk_iterator_customer(row), axis=1)


def bulk_iterator_customer(row):
    """
    Create object in customer model
    Fetches object from database if exist and update with fields passed in defaults dict otherwise create new
    """
    models.Customer.objects.update_or_create(
        name=row["CustomerName"],
        channel=models.Channel.objects.get(name=row["ChannelName"]),
        market=models.Market.objects.get(name=row["MarketName"])
    )
```

So using this I can successfully save those new objects in the database however this approach is quite bad perfomance wise.
For 150 or so rows in the excel file it takes 1100ms. I anticipate files to have 5000 or more rows which would mean that this approach is very slow.

Does anyone know alternative for saving objects in database from DataFrame?

Comment: It will probably be faster to `bulk_create` those objects, and just clean the duplicates later?

Comment: Or if you enforce the uniqueness on those three fields, you can use `bulk_create`'s `ignore_conflicts` to just ignore items that fail on unique constraint for objects that are already there

Comment: @bdbd Cleaning would also take time I think? So oyu say setting unique_together and using bulk create would be feasible solution? Ill try it but Im not sure if I want to set unqiue_together on those models though.

Comment: If you have the data already loaded into pandas, why don't you dedupe the rows before inserting into the db?

Comment: I think the biggest bottleneck in my way is saving each row from dataframe separately thats why going with bulk_create improves performance of this around 10 or 20 times. The thing is I need to add unique constraint to the model for it work.